# Alternating HTML table row classes using MVC3 EditorFor template

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, editorfor

I have googled as best I can but to no avail, hopefully this is a simple problem!

I am using an Html.EditorFor for a collection in a ViewModel object.

But I want the alternating rows of the table to have alternating class ( "odd", "even"). I tried using the following method that I picked up on SO but using it inside the Editor template resets the "count" value and it makes every  the same.

```
@helper AlternativeBackgrounds(string style1, string style2)
{
    if (ViewBag.count == null)
    {
        ViewBag.count = 0;
    }
    <text>class=" @(ViewBag.count % 2 == 1 ? style1 : style2)" </text>
    ViewBag.count++;
}
```

as in:

```
<tbody>
    <tr @AlternativeBackgrounds("odd", "even")>
        <td style="width:200px;">
```

Is this posible via code?

What i want to achieve:

```
<tbody>
     @Html.EditorFor(x => x.SomeCollection)               
</tbody>
```

Editor template

```
@model = SomeModel
<tr class=??>
    <td style="width:200px;">
       @Html.LabelFor(x => x.SomeProperty)   
    </td>
    <td>
       @Html.LabelFor(x => x.SomeProperty)
    </td>
    ... etc

</tr>
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing all that, can't you do it with javascript / jquery, and keep your actual code cleaner?

You'd just do

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.myTable tr:odd').addClass('oddRow');
});
```

if it's pure for styling reasons, you can use do it with CSS too, using [:nth-child(N)](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild):

```
tr:nth-child(even) { ... }
tr:nth-child(odd) { ... }
```